# How to go to start of Stream to avoid two webrequests?

Tags: c#, stream, webrequest

I have a small C# console app working that copies the results of a webrequest to a text file and then runs each command in that text file, saving the results to a separate text file.
Problem is, I have to make two requests to the same server, which I don't like doing. The problem is I can't seem to go to the beginning of the Stream/StreamReader after writing it to the text file, forcing me to make another request.
How do I do this with only one webrequest?
Thanks,
John

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Set all variables
        string epoUrl = "https://de-ser2012ecm:8443/remote/core.help.do";
        string commandHelpPath = @"C:\Logs\AllCommandsHelp.txt";
        string coreHelpPath = @"C:\Logs\CoreHelp.txt";
        string epoUsername = "admin";
        string epoPassword = "password";
        string responseFromServer;
        StringReader strReader;

        try
        {
            // Get stream from webrequest
            Stream coreStream = WebHelper.GetWebResponseStream(epoUrl, epoUsername, epoPassword);
            StreamReader coreReader = new StreamReader(coreStream);
            // Write core help page to text file
            using (StreamWriter corefile = new StreamWriter(coreHelpPath, true, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                responseFromServer = coreReader.ReadToEnd();
                // Display the content.
                corefile.Write(responseFromServer);
                strReader = new StringReader(responseFromServer);
            }

            // Get new stream from webrequest
            Stream commandStream = WebHelper.GetWebResponseStream(epoUrl, epoUsername, epoPassword);
            StreamReader commandReader = new StreamReader(commandStream);

            using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(commandHelpPath, true, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                while (!strReader.Peek().Equals(-1))
                {
                    string streamLine = strReader.ReadLine();
                    string[] words = streamLine.Split(' ');
                    // Check if first string contains a period that's not at the end
                    if ((words[0].Contains(".")) & !(words[0].EndsWith(".")))
                    {
                        StreamReader helpReader = WebHelper.GetWebResponse(epoUrl + "?command=" + words[0], epoUsername, epoPassword);
                        string helpResponseFromServer = helpReader.ReadToEnd();
                        outfile.Write(helpResponseFromServer);
                        outfile.WriteLine("==============================");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close streams
            //coreReader.Close();
            //commandReader.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

And the GetWebResponseStream method:

```
public static Stream GetWebResponseStream(string url, string username, string password)
    {
        Stream dataStream = null;

        try
        {
            // Set the credentials.
            CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
            credentialCache.Add(new System.Uri(url), "Basic", new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password));
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, cert, chain, ssl) => true;
            // Create a request for the URL. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Credentials = credentialCache;
            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            return dataStream;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GetWebResponse threw an exception: " + ex.Message);
            return dataStream;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about first writing the response into a MemoryStream? Then you can safely seek the MemoryStream.

Comment: And why do you need to read from the stream again? You already have the content in the variable `responseFromServer`. You can just use it.

Comment: @Gildor is right, but I think you should declare `responseFromServer` at the beginning of Main so it doesn't go out of scope.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried to use MemoryStream before but it doesn't have a WriteLine method, something I need in order to access each line of the initial stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gildor for the suggestion that put me on the right track. I had the response, I just needed to copy that string into a StringReader. This automatically resets the cursor so you can read from the top! I updated the code to show the new fix. Thanks to everyone for the suggestions. John

Comment: Great that you figured out!